# Browse to a Directory and have the Path stored in a string (C#)

Tags: c#, string, file-io, dialog

I'm trying to make this program in C# using WPF in Visual Studio. This is basically what it has to do.

When a button called "Browse" is clicked on the main form, it will open up a new form/window that let's the user browse to any directory that he chooses. After he selects the folder and clicks "Open" (or some other button on that form), the path of that directory, for example, "C:\temp" will be stored in a string variable so it can used later.

My first problem is, what do I write in the even handler of the "Browse" button that will open up a window that let's the user browse and select a folder? Is there a default window I can use or do I have to create a new form for it? Please note, the user has to select a folder, not a file like the default "Open" window.

Secondly, how do I reference a string variable so that it stores the path of the directory that the user selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type you are looking for is the `OpenFileDialog`

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx

The basic usage is the following

```
using (FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
  if (DialogResult.Ok == fileDialog.ShowDialog()) {
    string fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Comments clarified OP is looking to open a directory vs. a file.  For this you need the `FolderBrowseDialog`

```
var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: with this one, the user has to choose a file no? I want the user to be able to choose a folder rather than a specific file.

Comment: @SteveWay this allows for directories as well

Comment: There is a FolderBrowser, too.

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors. http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/12423955/1024/Anonymous/WpfApplication2---Microsoft-Visual-Studio-%28Adminis.jpg

Comment: Looks like your in a WPF app. Try this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @JaredPar how to configure this dialog for selecting folder? Your example is for files. In this case it is required to choose some file in the dialog.

Comment: that's for windows forms, I need it for WPF

Answer (score 1):

For choosing directory you should use [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx). It's a control from WinForms. WPF doesn't have it's own.

For example:

```
var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    // ...
```

Don't forget to add reference to the `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: how can I do this with WPF because I'm doing this for an assignment at university and the requirement is that I use WPF?

Comment: WPF doesn't have it's own dialog for selecting folder (where you see a directories tree). You can use such dialog only from WinForms (need to include reference to System.Windows.Forms). I've already described this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this on Button Click

```
        FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        folderpathTB.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
```

(folderpathTB is name of TextBox where I wana put the file path, OR u can assign it to a string variable too)